# Is it possible that $mx^2-x+1=0$ has two negative roots?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, roots, quadratics

> If the expression $(mx-1+\frac1x)$ is non-negative for all positive real $x$, then find the minimum value of $m$.

Given, $\frac{mx^2-x+1}x\ge0$ for all positive real $x$.

$\implies mx^2-x+1\ge0$ for all positive real $x$.

If $m\gt0$ and discriminant$\le0\implies1-4m\le0$, I am getting minimum value of $m$ as $1/4$, which is the correct answer.

But I wonder what if $m\gt0$, Discriminant$\ge0$ and both roots are negative? (Here, the quadratic is positive for positive $x$). Do we need to consider this? If yes, how to reach the answer in this case?

Comment: Both roots can't be negative (or, more precisely, nonpositive, $0$ included) if $m>0$, since their sum is $\frac{1}{m}>0$. But you are correct that one should consider this case, if only to rule it out.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question in your title does not really correspond with your text.  The point of the text question is that you are looking for cases when the quadratic has no (real) roots, or just a single root.  But I will answer the question in the title.

Think of the graph of $y=mx^2-x+1$.  It cuts the $y$ axis at $y=1$ which is of course positive.  If $m$ is negative, then the parabola is concave downwards and will have two roots, one positive and one negative.  (Draw the graph!)

If $m$ is positive then the parabola is concave upwards and the vertex is at $x=1/(2m)$ which is positive.  If there are two roots, then one will be between $x=0$ and $x=1/(2m)$, therefore positive; and the other will be greater than $x=1/(2m)$, therefore also positive.  (Draw the graph!)

Comment: Thankyou, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $m \ne0.$ The equation is equivalent to $$x^2 -\frac{x}{m}+\frac{1}{m}=0.$$ The product of the roots is $1/m$. If both roots are negative, $m$ must be positive. The sum of the roots is $1/m.$ But then if both roots are negative, $m$ must be negative. Contradiction.

Comment: Thankyou, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

To follow through on your question about the discriminant:

The zeroes of the quadratic polynomial are
$$ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{2m} \ \pm \ \frac{\sqrt{1 \ - \ 4m}}{2m} \ \ . $$
As you already observed, there are no real zeroes for $ \ 1 - 4m \ < \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ m \ > \ \frac14 \ \ . \ $  At $ \ m \ = \ \frac14 \ \ , \ $ the polynomial has a "double zero" at $ \ x \ = \ 2 \ \ $ (having become $ \ \frac14 x^2 - x + 1 \ = \ \frac14 · (x^2 - 4x + 4) $ $ = \ \frac14·(x - 2)^2 \ \ . \ $

The "degenerate" (linear) case of $ \ m \ = \ 0 \ \ $ (with single zero $ \ x \ = \ 1 \ ) \ $ separates the remaining values of $ \ m \ $ into two intervals.  For $ \ m \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ \sqrt{1 - 4m} \ > \ 1 \ \ , \ $ so it is clear that $$   \frac{1}{2m} \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{1 \ - \ 4m}}{2m} \ \ > \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
thus only one of the zeroes is negative.
In the interval $ \ 0 \ < \ m \ < \ \frac14 \ \ , \ \ 0 \ > \ -4m \ > \ -1 $ $ \Rightarrow \ 0 \ < \ 1 - 4m \ < \ 1 \ \Rightarrow \ 0 \ < \   \sqrt{1 - 4m} \ < \ 1 \ \ , \ $ and we will still have
$$   \frac{1}{2m} \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{1 \ - \ 4m}}{2m} \ \ > \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
so both zeroes are positive.  Hence, it is not possible for both zeroes to be negative.  (In this approach, examining only the discriminant does not provide enough information:  we need to look at the full expression for the zeroes.)